# Error when combining Json api response and my own Json data

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to combine movie data from OMDBAPI with myown data which is some additional information about the movie.

Myjson data // I have 10 movies

```
{
"Movie1": {
    "id": "01",
    "Title": "Disney Princess Enchanted Tales: Follow Your Dreams",
    "Characters": ["Sleeping Beauty"," Princess Jasmine"," Rajah", " Jago", " Kong Stefan", " Kong Henrik", " Fauna", " Flora"],
    "Actors": ["Erin Torpey", " Lea Salong", " Frank Welker", " Gilbert Gottfried", " Corey Burton", " Jeff Bennett", " Russi Taylor", " Barbara Dirikson"],
    "DirectedBy": "David Block",
    "ProducedBy": ["Kurt Albrecht", " Douglas Segal"]
},
"Movie2": {
    "id": "02",
    "Title": "Disney Princess Stories Volume Two: Tales of Friendship",
    "Characters": ["Ariel", " Snow White", " Princess Jasmine", " Girl"],
    "Actors": ["Jodi Benson", " Carolyn Gardner", " Linda larkin", " Ashley Edner"],
    "DirectedBy": ["Rob LaDuca", " Jamie Mitchell", " Kazou Terada"],
    "ProducedBy": ["Paul Betzold", " Andrew Carlson"]
},
```

FUNCTION

I'm trying to append the OMDBAPI data in a ul and a li.
And as you can see i'm also trying to loop through 1-10 and inside the loop appling my json which i'm trying to display with a id and the iterated i number.

```
//now we are querying and prepare the results for display;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(omdb_request, function(results) {

    console.log(omdb_request);

    $.each(results.Search, function(idx, item) {
      for (var $i = 1; $i <= 10; i++) {
        $.getJSON("json/Metadata.json", function(myjson) {
          console.log(myjson);

          $('ul.movie_list').append('<li><p><strong>Title:</strong> ' + results.Search[idx].Title + '</p><p><strong>Year:</strong> ' + results.Search[idx].Year + '</p><img src="' + results.Search[idx].Poster + '" alt="' + results.Search[idx].Title + '"</img><div id="myjson' + $i + '"></div></li>');
          i++;
        })

      };
    });
  })
});
```

I'm adding this picture to show my results in the inspectertool in chrome
[image: inspectortool]

Another picture to show what i would like to do
[image: picture]

I hope you can help me with my function maybe i can do something instead of my forloop?

Comment: The iteration variable is `$i`, but you're incrementing `i`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue regarding your use of `$.getJSON()` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have two object one is your custom data:

```
var myData={
"movieName":"ABC"
}
```

and another one from the api

```
var apiData={
"movieName":"DEF"
}
```

Then you can merge it and save it into another variable.

```
const mergedVar = {};
$.extend(mergedVar , myData, apiData);
```

In you case you can save the result from the api to a new variable and merge it. You can read more about $.extend here [enter link description here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-target-object1-objectN)

Comment: That's not correct syntax for objects. `=` should be `:`

Comment: thank you, slipped my mind :) have edited it.